# Setting kendoui treeview's checkbox's checked property to true on load

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, treeview, kendo-ui, checkbox

Here's how I'm binding my kendoui treeview

```
  @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
  .Name("treeview")
  .Checkboxes(chkbxs =>
    {
       chkbxs.CheckChildren(true);
    })
  .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.inlineDefault)
   )
```

how do I set some of the checkboxes checked property to true, on load? There's a bool property in `TreeViewItemModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ItemAction` method to provide a delegate which sets the `Checked` property to `true` on each `TreeViewItem`.

Additionally you can write any conditional logic inside the `ItemAction` to only check some of them:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
  .Name("treeview")
  .Checkboxes(chkbxs =>
    {                
       chkbxs.CheckChildren(true);
    })
  .ItemAction(item =>
    {
       if (checkSomeCondition(item))
           item.Checked = true;
    })
  .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.inlineDefault)
  )
```

Comment: But I do not want all to be true

Comment: @PapyrusBit sorry I've missed the some part. But still you can use the ItemAction... see my update answer. Based on what criteria you want to set them to true?